# Sending base address of vector for Iterating

Tags: c++

I am having result class with some properties

```
class Result
{
   public:
   GetId();
   GetName();
   SetName();
   SetId();

};
```

I have one more class which will create result arraylike

```
class A
{
  public:
   void Method()
   {
     //array of result using vector
    Callback->OnCallback(array of result);
   }
```

};

Now i have callback class

```
class Callback
{
  public:
 void OnCallback(Result*)
 {
   //Need to loop through result;
 }
};
```

Now I need mechanism to loop through result array in OnCallback method, but i dont need to send result as vector/array. I just need to send base address from Class A Method() to OnCallback method. How can i achive it?

Comment: Wouldn't you prefer a simpler example?

Comment: currently have created

Comment: struct { int cout; Result* res} and in Class A Method i am setting vales count = sizeofVector; res = vec[0]. but when i recieve call back i can acess only 0th value and other values are giving null exception

Comment: why not show the code where you actually try to loop through the values and get the exception? also show the code where you create/fill the array/vector.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. Does this help?

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int* p)
{
  for(unsigned int k=0; k<3; ++k)
    std::cout << *(p+k) << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  int A[3];

  A[0] = 10;
  A[1] = 11;
  A[2] = 12;

  foo(A);

  return 0;
}
```

Note that the calling function (`main`) passes `A`, not `A[0]`.

Answer (score -2):

If you make a object of type `Result` Like this:

```
Result r1;
```

then you can pass it like this:

```
Callback->OnCallback(&r1);
```

Which will pass the *address* (because of the `&` symbol) and not the object itself.

Comment: currently have created
struct { int cout; Result* res} and in Class A Method i am setting vales count = sizeofVector; res = vec[0]. but when i recieve call back i can acess only 0th value and other values are giving null exception